# convert to Linq(lambda expression) - select only one table with join

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use linq in lambda I want to select only one of the join table 
like

```
select r* from report r left join favorites f on f.reportid = r.reportid
```

here's what I have now, and I want to assign the result to the model object

```
List<Report> reports = new List<Report>(db.UserFavorites
                                        .Join(db.Reports, fav => fav.ReportID, rep => rep.Report_ID,((fav,rep) => new Report (rep)))
                                         .Where(x => x.Favorites.UserID == new Guid(userID))
                                         .Select new { rep }
                                         .ToList()
                                        );
return reports;
```

Im getting stuct with the selection. will the result become anonymous or it will retain the Report object?

Comment: Could you please explain the issue? Use of `new` keyword is not forced and your resutlset will not be anonymous if you don't use `new`.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. ToList already returns a list, no need to copy it again by calling `new List<Report>`.
2. `rep` is of type Report, so just do `(fav, rep) => rep` instead of creating a new Report instance.
3. Your Select part doesn’t even compile, and like I mentioned in point 2 you would just return `rep`, i.e. `Select(rep => rep)`. However, if you return your input you can omit the Select altogether.

In total it should be like this:

```
List<Report> reports = db.UserFavorites
  .Join(db.Reports, fav => fav.ReportID, rep => rep.Report_ID, (fav, rep) => rep)
  .Where(x => x.Favorites.UserID == new Guid(userID))
  .ToList();
return reports;
```

Comment: One little nitpick is that this code (and the OP's code) does not do a _left_ join, it is doing an _inner_ join.  The OP's sql statement shows a left join.